# Can't seem to POST using Python and Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, json, node.js

I've looked at various posts on this topic but am still running into an error with this.

Python code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/ay'
payload = {'some': 'data'}
r = requests.post(url,  data=payload)

print r.text
print r.status_code
```

Node.js code:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.post('/ay', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('done');
});
```

So I've looked at my `req` and even `req.body` but `req.body` returns `undefined` so I think it's with `json=payload` but I've also tried `params=payload` and `data=json.dumps(payload)`

Edit: I forgot to include bodyparser and urlencoded. I edited my code to show the changes.

Comment: Are you using the appropriate form parsing middleware on the server side?

Comment: What would that be? Do you mean something like express?

Comment: If you're submitting JSON, you need some kind of middleware that can parse that type of request (e.g. the `body-parser` module's JSON middleware).

Comment: Did your codes including `body-parser` to parse the json request? `var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: I tried that but the body is now {} ... so at least not undefined now. But I'm still not seeing some:data on the node.js side - is it because of the python code now?

Comment: @user1883614 I am having the same issue - req.body is {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **body-parser** to get JSON from request body

```
var bodyparser = require('body-parser'); 
app.use(bodyparser.json());
```

Comment: I tried that but the body is now {} ... so at least not undefined now. But I'm still not seeing some:data on the node.js side - is it because of the python code now?